# Query tables from a list of ids

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a way to query tables from a list of ID's in Mysql. I have a query that works in postgres and SQL Server that looks like this:

```
SELECT a.vehicle_id, a.make, a.model, b.id as people_id, b.name as owner
FROM (values (6,3),(7,3),(3,4),(4,2)) as jt (vehicle_id, people_id)
JOIN vehicles a ON (a.vehicle_id = jt.vehicle_id AND a.people_id = jt.people_id)
JOIN people b ON (b.id = v.people_id)
```

So I have an array of id's that are the same as vehicle_id and people_id.
I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in MySQL or if I need to convert the ID's and add them to a where clause? That could get pretty horrendous looking like this: `WHERE (a.vehicle_id = 3 AND a.people_id = 4) OR (a.vehicle_id = 4 AND a.people_id = 2) OR … etc`

Comment: You can do `where (x,y) in ((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))`

Comment: @Strawberry Please put that as the answer. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer contributed by @Strawberry. This one does the trick nicely!
Assigning the ID's to fields in a where clause:

```
SELECT a.vehicle_id, a.make, a.model, b.id as people_id, b.name as owner
FROM vehicles a
JOIN people b ON (b.id = a.people_id)
WHERE (vehicle_id, people_id) IN ((6,3),(7,3),(3,4),(4,2))
```

Comment: It might be useful to compare the EXPLAINs for this method and you 'OR' method

Comment: Indeed! I'll wait till I have this in a working environment where I have a lot more ID's in the query and compare the two. I'll post back when I have it.